# Re-implementing OpenCL kernel of affine transform with bilinear interpolation in python

Tags: python, opencl, interpolation

I have an OpenCL kernel which does affine transformation with bilinear interpolation. I want to reimplement that kernel in python.

Following is the OpenCL kernel for affine transformation with bilinear interpolation:

```
#ifndef SAMPLER_FILTER
#define SAMPLER_FILTER CLK_FILTER_LINEAR
#endif

#ifndef SAMPLER_ADDRESS
#define SAMPLER_ADDRESS CLK_ADDRESS_CLAMP
#endif

__kernel void affine_transform_2d_interpolate(
    IMAGE_input_TYPE input,
    IMAGE_output_TYPE output,
    IMAGE_mat_TYPE mat)
{

  const sampler_t sampler = CLK_NORMALIZED_COORDS_TRUE|
      SAMPLER_ADDRESS | SAMPLER_FILTER;

  uint i = get_global_id(0);
  uint j = get_global_id(1);

  uint Nx = GET_IMAGE_WIDTH(input);
  uint Ny = GET_IMAGE_HEIGHT(input);

  float x = i+0.5f;
  float y = j+0.5f;

  float y2 = (mat[3]*x+mat[4]*y+mat[5]);
  float x2 = (mat[0]*x+mat[1]*y+mat[2]);

  float2 coord_norm = (float2)(x2/Nx,y2/Ny);

  float pix = (float)(READ_input_IMAGE(input, sampler, coord_norm).x);
  int2 pos = (int2){i, j};

  WRITE_output_IMAGE(output, pos, CONVERT_output_PIXEL_TYPE(pix));
  
}
```

Following is the output from the kernel:

[image: Desired Output]

Following is the reimplementation of the above kernel in python.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.io import imshow

def bilinear_interpolation(input_matrix, output_size):
    input_height, input_width = input_matrix.shape
    output_height, output_width = output_size

    x_ratio = (input_width - 1) / float(output_width - 1)
    y_ratio = (input_height - 1) / float(output_height - 1)

    output_matrix = np.zeros(output_size)

    input_height = input_height - 1
    input_width = input_width - 1 
    for y in range(output_height):
        for x in range(output_width):
            mat = [0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0]

            x_input = mat[0]*x+mat[1]*y+mat[2]
            y_input = mat[3]*x+mat[4]*y+mat[5]
            
            # x_floor = int(np.floor(x_input))
            # y_floor = int(np.floor(y_input))
            x_floor = int(x_input)
            y_floor = int(y_input)

            x_weight = x_input - x_floor
            y_weight = y_input - y_floor
            
            top_left = input_matrix[x_floor, y_floor]
            top_right = input_matrix[(x_floor-1) if (x_floor+1)>input_width else (x_floor+1), (y_floor)]
            bottom_left = input_matrix[(x_floor), (y_floor-1) if (y_floor+1)>input_height else (y_floor+1)]
            bottom_right = input_matrix[(x_floor-1) if (x_floor+1)>input_width else (x_floor+1),
                                        (y_floor-1) if (y_floor+1)>input_height else (y_floor+1)]

            interpolated_value = (
                top_left * (1 - x_weight) * (1 - y_weight) +
                top_right * x_weight * (1 - y_weight) +
                bottom_left * (1 - x_weight) * y_weight +
                bottom_right * x_weight * y_weight
            )

            output_matrix[y, x] = interpolated_value

    return output_matrix

# Input 2x2 matrix
input_matrix = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

# Output 10x10 matrix
output_size = (10, 10)

# Perform bilinear interpolation
output_matrix = bilinear_interpolation(input_matrix, output_size)

imshow(output_matrix)
```

This is the output I get after running the python reimplementation:

[image: Current Output]

I am not able to figure out what is wrong in the python reimplementation.